# What does this C++ syntax mean?

Tags: c++, syntax

Here's the statement. I believe this is using a cast operator, but what's the deal with the post increment?

```
(*C)(x_i,gi_tn,f)++;
```

Declaration and definition of `C`:

```
std::auto_ptr<conditional_density> C(new conditional_density());
```

Declaration of the `conditional_density` class:

```
class conditional_density: public datmoConditionalDensity{
public:
  static const double l_min, l_max, delta;
  static double x_scale[X_COUNT];    // input log luminance scale
  double *g_scale;    // contrast scale
  double *f_scale;    // frequency scale      
  const double g_max;    
  double total;    
  int x_count, g_count, f_count; // Number of elements    
  double *C;          // Conditional probability function    
  conditional_density( const float pix_per_deg = 30.f ) :
    g_max( 0.7f ){
    //Irrelevant to the question               
  }    

  double& operator()( int x, int g, int f )
  {
    assert( (x + g*x_count + f*x_count*g_count >= 0) && (x + g*x_count + f*x_count*g_count < x_count*g_count*f_count) );
    return C[x + g*x_count + f*x_count*g_count];
  }

};
```

The parent class, `datmoConditionalDensity`, only has a virtual destructor.

It would have been easy to answer this by debugging the code, but this code won't build under Windows (needs a bunch of external libraries).

Comment: The motto behind that particular line of code being: Readability is for wimps?

Comment: @Grizzly, real programmers do it all in one line...with the screen turned off...in the dark...while using a pen. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(*C)(x_i,gi_tn,f)++;
```

Let's break it down:

```
(*C)
```

This dereferences the pointer. C is a smart pointer, and thus can be dereferenced to get the actual element being pointed to. The result is a `conditional_density` object.

```
(*C)(x_i,gi_tn,f)
```

This calls the the overloaded `()` operator in the `conditional_density` class. It can be strange to see it the first time, but it is an operator just like everything else. Bottom line is that it calls this code:

```
  double& operator()( int x, int g, int f )
  {
    assert( (x + g*x_count + f*x_count*g_count >= 0) && (x + g*x_count + f*x_count*g_count < x_count*g_count*f_count) );
    return C[x + g*x_count + f*x_count*g_count];
  }
```

which returns a reference to a double. Finally:

```
(*C)(x_i,gi_tn,f)++
```

Because the overloaded `()` operator returns a reference to a double, I can use `++` on it which increments the double.

Comment: @akappa, you're right, I was thinking about the comma operator (don't ask me why). My bad :)

Answer (score 3):

If I'm interpreting this correctly, `C` is a pointer to a function object (something that has an `operator()` defined).  This means that

```
(*C)(x_i,gi_tn,f)
```

Means "dereference `C` to get back the function object, then invoke it with arguments `x_i`, `gi_tn`, and `f`.  Note that the function returns a `double&`, so this line

```
(*C)(x_i,gi_tn,f)++;
```

means "dereference C, call the function with the appropriate arguments, and finally postincrement the result."

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The operator()(int, int, int) returns a reference to an element of the static array of double.

The ++ operator increments the value that was returned.